# whats the logic behind the following loop?

Tags: loops

please anyone explain me the logic behind this piece of looping.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 0;

    while (true) {
        number = number + 1;

        if (number >= 5) {
            break;
        }

        if (number < 5) {
            continue;
        }

        System.out.print(number + " ");
    }

    System.out.print(number + " ");
}
```

Comment: This looks like a homework. Sadly, StackOverflow is not a "do my homework for me" site. Therefore, I'm voting to close this thread. You can **edit** your question (showing what you already tried) to convince readers of the opposite - and reopen the thread again.

Comment: sorry to bother you .. i am new to programming and learning stuffs on my own.. and moreover am not a school going kid to have a homework buddy.. peace..

Comment: Don't get me wrong - I'm not bothered (and I don't take it personal at all). You are absolutely welcome at Stack Overflow, including questions that you have as a newcomer of programming - especially when you teach yourself programming as an autodidact! Please take a short moment to take the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for SO newcomers - it really doesn't take more than five minutes. Here you also find a guide how to formulate questions: State the problem, show what you already tried, show what happened when you tried. Peace. And good luck learning to program.

Answer (score 0):

`while(true)` means an infinite loop and it will only `break;` the loop `if(number >= 5)` is true.

`continue;` means to ignore the succeeding commands and proceed to the next loop, therefore print function at the bottom of the loop will only execute `if(number<5)` is false (but will never happen because of the `break;` command above)

when the loop exits, the `number`'s last value will be printed.